# RankOver Partition by with minutes and seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to sequence data and as it occurs there are instances where I have to order this sequence using hour/minutes and seconds. However when I use the rank/partition by function, it's almost as if it does not recognize this as chronological data at all. An example of the data I am trying to sequence is below:

```
Mod_Order   Last_Activity   ACTIVITY_DATE_DTTM     hdm_modif_dttm

1           NULL            15/08/2007 00:00:00     59:47.3
2           NULL            27/09/2007 14:30:02     59:22.9
3           NULL            27/11/2007 15:30:02     59:10.5
3           NULL            27/11/2007 15:30:02     58:38.9
```

As you can see the last two ACTIVITY_DATE_DTTM date times are exactly the same so I need to go a step further - I removed the date from the hdm_modif_dttm field to see if it made any difference but it does not (I left it as time though as I figured it does not make any difference anyhow). So my code was as follows:

```
Update q
        set q.Mod_Order = b.Mod_Order

from [#Temp_last_act_2]q
Left join
        (
select
    RANK () over 
    (partition by pathway_id
    order by pathway_id, ACTIVITY_DATE_DTTM,hdm_modif_dttm)   as Mod_Order,
    PATHWAY_ID,
    MODIF_DTTM,
    ACTIVITY_DATE_DTTM
    from #temp_Last_act_2
    ) as b on b.PATHWAY_ID = q.PATHWAY_ID 
        and b.MODIF_DTTM = q.MODIF_DTTM
        and b.ACTIVITY_DATE_DTTM = q.ACTIVITY_DATE_DTTM
```

Is anyone aware of any limitations using this function that I am unaware of or is there a function that may handle this better (or am I being really daft?)

Comment: What happens? This should give you a rank within each `pathway_id` based on `activity_date_dttm` and then `hdm_modif_dttm`, is it producing an error or just not the rankings you expect? Also, what are your column datatypes?

Comment: Hi @Chris - the problem is I need to rank on the milliseconds and it does not look like the rank function recognises this part of the datetime..